# ssh command in script - remove lines from output

Tags: linux, ssh

Using output of ssh in a script; but getting additional ssh output lines on connecting to host

```
ssh   www@192.168.2.2 << EOF
curl /abc 
EOF
```

only interested in output of curl

like getting additional lines like :

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-37-generic x86_64) 
* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com * Management: 
https://landscape.canonical.com 
* Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage 
* Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
```

Comment: try `ssh www@192.168.2.2 /bin/bash << EOF` just tested it and not getting output/welcome banner

Comment: Super .. worked !

Comment: Close voters: Trying to do this _in a script_ is a programming task, not general computing.  I don't think this should be closed.